# Check the value gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory from .NET code

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm trying to confirm that various runtime settings we have changed are being applied to my application.  In particular the `gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory` in the **runtime** section of the `Aspnet.config` file.  How can I check the value of that for my current application?

I obviously could go read that `.config` file, but I want to check the running value of MY apps runtime.

I've tried searching for this to no avail.  Calling `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("runtime")` just returns an `System.Configuration.IgnoreSection` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with reading the `.config` file manually (and indeed that is what I'm doing in a related case). Think about it, when you're using the `System.Configuration` APIs that is what happens in the background as well. So, even if unfortunate [1], when they don't expose the `runtime`-Section, you can still read the manually and end up with the same effect.

The accuracy of the results should also be equally well. If someone would change the values of those settings *after* the application has started, `ConfigurationManage` would theoretically also see those values, even though they are "stale". So a self-reading approach is no worse here.

FWIW, you could use the following xpaths to read the value you're after (plus two more that are often of interest here):

```
/configuration/runtime/gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory/@enabled

/configuration/runtime/gcServer/@enabled
/configuration/runtime/gcConcurrent/@enabled
```

Other than writing your own (native DLL) and poking inside the memory of the CLR, the actual runtime-value of the "trim commit" setting seems not be be exposed to applications.
You can [search](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory) through the CoreCLR source code to see how the configuration value unfolds.

In an ASP.NET application, you'd have to find the aspnet.config file that is actually used by your application's pool. I have no experience here, but [this](http://blogs.iis.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool) article provides more information.

[1] I think that the runtime section is not mapped to a proper configuration section, and even ignored by the managed `ConfigurationManager`, because it is read by the native startup code of the CLR and thus "of no interest" to the managed code.